# Special Folder "Common Application Data Folder" not available in my setup project. Why?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, special-folders

I want to create a **Visual Studio 2010 setup project** that deploys some files to a folder where my application can use it from. I want it so, that all users have the same files, and that they also could manipulate them without admin rights.

Thus, "Common Application Data Folder"* as [described in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), seems fine.

However, in my Visual Studio 2010 setup project **I did not find the "Common Application Data Folder" available in the "Add special Folder..." drop down menu.**

**I have a .NET 4.0 WinForms app and see no reason why this does not show up.**
The *user's* common application data folder is available but does not match my intended use.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: There is no folder available in a standard Windows install that all users can write to.  CADF is read-only.  You'll need to create such a folder yourself.  A server share is best, users overwriting each others data is never not a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: "Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData" is writable. I can access it with the Environment.GetFolderPath() call. I use it in my application, and it works well. However, the installer should put some initial content there for my app to use later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio setup projects do not have a predefined folder for common Application Data. However, you can install files in it like this:

- add a custom folder and select it
- in its Properties pane set **DefaultLocation** to:

```
[CommonAppDataFolder]
```

- in this folder add the files you want installed in common Application Data

During install [CommonAppDataFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will be automatically resolved by Windows Installer.

Answer (score 8):

A more specific solution might be to set the **DefaultLocation** property to:

```
[CommonAppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
```

**Manufacturer** and **ProductName** will be resolved from the values you assign to the corresponding  properties of the setup project.