# set total control permission on my visual .net installation application folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, folder-permissions

I have developed a winform application in Visual Studio 2010. I created a setup project to make the install of the app.

When I install the app and I choose a drive like D:\MyAPP I have no problem and I could ran my app without problems, but when I install the app in c:\program files\MyAPP I have problems because the folder and the files in it doesnt have all permission for all users, so an example is that I cant write in the database file (sqlce).

Is there anything I can do? Is there a configuration on the setup project ? can I give all permission to all users over the folder intallation and its files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Permissions on c:\Program files" is a Vista/Win7 thing.  Here's a good link:

- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?564256-Classic-VB-Where-should-I-store-the-files-that-my-program-uses-creates

Comment: thanks. It´s very interesting that article because explains the installation strategy

Comment: Here is how to make it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531119/special-folder-common-application-data-folder-not-available-in-my-setup-projec