# Where do I store program resources?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have just finished my first proper program. I'm done with all the testing and it all works sound.

What concerns me is that I'm not sure that i have saved all of the "outside of the program" stuff in the correct place. I have an access database, a text file and a few sound files stored in the debug folder that was created when I started making the program. All of the strings I use have the specific location of these elements. for example: `filelocation = "C:\Computer Science Coursework 2019\Main Program Coursework\Main Program Coursework\bin\Debug\LanguageAndFont.txt"`

My question is, will all of these be somehow 'integrated' with the program when its compiled? and even if, what if I want to debug on a different PC. I know there is a resources folder, and I hold a few images and icons there, but I don't suppose I could drag a database there?

Is there a way I could store all of these *in* the program, so that any PC can debug it?

Comment: You may want to used the built in Resources. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-resources-object

Comment: I know I can keep the audio files there, but what about the database?

Comment: Is this a multi user database or just meant for the user of the program?

Comment: Just for the program

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806433/where-to-put-my-access-database-in-computer

Comment: Resources are something specific, i.e. data compiled into your assembly. Files aren't resources. The Resources folder in the Solution Explorer contains the source for your resources. When you built, those files are read and the contents compiled into your EXE. Resources are basically read-only. Part of their appeal is that the user can't change them. You don't make a database a resource. Fixed text files, sound files, image files, etc, are the sorts of things to add to your resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically store text files or any other files in other computers, you may use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` to get `SET` variables. Just type `SET` in Command Prompt to list all set variables (we're using only location variables in this case).

Documentation for writing files could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1) to write your resource files. For example:

```
Private fileLocation = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE").ToString +
                       "\MyProjectLocation\hello.txt"

My.Computer.Filesystem.WriteAllText(fileLocation, "some text in hello world", false)
```

And if you want to read back the text again, just simply use `ReadAllText()`.

```
My.Computer.Filesystem.ReadAllText(fileLocation)
```

This is the easiest method for writing and reading files with dynamic locations which is available in everyone's Windows system.

---

**Note:** You should use `My.Settings` here for easy & manageable code. You can define variables for `My.Settings.(varName)` by going to Project Settings > Settings. But make sure the program isn't migrated to somewhere else after usage. The Settings is saved for the specified path only. It won't work if the application's path is changed.

Hope it helps you.